# What is the equivalent of recursion in a function with yield?

Tags: python, list, function, generator

So i've been learning about generators and came across this code

```
def flatten(a):
    for i in a:
        try: 
            yield from flatten(i)
        except TypeError: 
            yield i
a = list(flatten([1, 2, 2, 3, [1, 2, 68,[[98, 85 ,97],67]]]))
```

From what i understand right now the equivalent of calling a function back inside of the function itself is done with yield from flatten(i) in this case. I tried changing the code to yield flatten(i) but then a lot of weird things happen, instead of flattening my list the code returns a list of generator objects. Is there a reason for that? Is there something i am missing about generator functions?

Comment: `flatten` is a generator, so yielding it yields a generator. `yield from` specifically “unpacks” the generator and yields its values.

Comment: So basically, from yield looks at all the values that are found in the recursion until you hit the bottom of your recursion, and yields that last number?

Comment: Replace `yield from flatten(i)` with `for x in flatten(i): yield x`. It means the same thing, but that might help you understand it better.